# Does it matter where is the inline keyword is specified, base class, derived class or both?

Tags: c++, inheritance, inline, virtual

Suppose we wan't to hint the compiler to inline member function where applicable.

```
class Base
{
 public:
      inline virtual f() = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
 public:
      virtual f() override; // no inline specifier here
};
```

Do I need to specify `inline` in `Derived::f()` or can I omit the keyword and be sure that `virtual Derived::f()` is the same thing as `inline Derived::f()` ?

I mean is the `inline` keyword implicitly specified for `Derived::f()` or do I need to explicitly type it once again?

Comment: It's extremely unlikely that the compiler pays any attention to the `inline` keyword for virtual methods. It's only possible to do any kind of an optimization in this area when the compiler can prove what most-derived instance of the class actually is. Only realistically possible for instances of objects created in static or auto scope. Unlikely when referenced via pointers, or references.

Comment: No number of `inline` keywords will help if you are not going to provide the actual implementation of the function in the header. If the implementation is not visible at the call site, there's nothing to inline. Besides, virtual function calls generally cannot be inlined - the compiler can't be sure at compile time which override would need to be called.

Comment: So if function is defined in the header and object is not referenced by pointer or reference, then inlining is most likely possible, but anayway in that case does it matter if inline is specified in base or derived class or both? that is what bothers me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I need to specify `inline` in `Derived::f()` or can I omit the keyword and be sure that `virtual Derived::f()` is the same thing as `inline Derived::f()` ?

If you omit the `inline` keyword in the derived class, it is not `inline` in the derived class.

> I mean is the `inline` keyword implicitly specified for `Derived::f()`

No, it is not.

> or do I need to explicitly type it once again?

Yes, you do. However, a compiler will most likely generate code for it as though it is a non-`inline` member function since it is a `virtual` member function.

Comment: Sorry I find your anwser somewhat ambiguons, first you say I don't need to specify inline in derived class, and then you say I do need to explicitly specify the keyword. Can you please reword your first anwser. (first out of 3)

Answer (score 1):

#### What does the inline keyword do?

Modern compilers try to balance the costs of inlining a function with the benefits.

Both the benefits and the costs are pretty clear: When a function gets inlined, there's no overhead to the function call (since there is no function call), and the compiler is able to do optimizations to the body of the function based on the context within which it's being called (since, when it's inlined, it knows that context).

Costs may include increased executable size (if it's a big function), and more instances of the assembly for the body of the function being plastered around the executable.

A rule of thumb is that if a function is big or complex, it probably won't be inlined. If it's small, it probably will be inlined.

This is good. It prevents bloated executables, but still eliminates nearly all the overhead associated with using functions. The time to execute a big, complex function oftentimes *dwarfs* the cost of the function call, and inlining it would have only minimal benefit.

**So what does `inline` do?** The compiler calculates how complex a function is when deciding to inline it. It then compares that calculation to some threshold. If the function is less complex than the threshold, it inlines the function.

The `inline` keyword *basically* raises the threshold for that particular function, but what it actually does under the hood varies from compiler to compiler.

#### Can all function calls be inlined?

If the compiler doesn't know what function is getting called, it can't inline it.

Let's look at an example:

```
// func_t is a pointer to a function that returns an integer
using func_t = int(*)(); 
int getNumber(func_t func) {
    // The compiler can't inline func(), because it doesn't know
    // what func *is*
    return func(); 
}
```

#### How does this apply to virtual functions?

A virtual function call is pretty similar to invoking a function pointer, but with a few key differences. If you're invoking it from the base class, the compiler doesn't know ahead of time what function to invoke:

```
class Base {
    virtual int getNum() { return 0; }
};

class Derived {
    int value; 
    void setValue(int v) { value = v; }
    int getNum() override { return value; }
}; 

int getNumFrom(Base& base) {
    // The compiler doesn't know whether to call
    // Base::getNum() or Derived::getNum(), so it can't inline it
    return base.getNum();
}
```

However, if you're invoking it from a concrete instance of a class (not a reference, and not a pointer, the compiler knows exactly which version is getting called:

```
int getNumFromDerived() {
    Derived d; 
    // Here, we know that we're calling Derived::getNum()
    // so the compiler *can* inline it. 
    return d.getNum(); 
}
```

#### How should you apply the inline keyword?

You can specify it both in the base class, and in the derived class. Just know that it *won't* guarantee they get inlined, precisely because sometimes it's impossible to inline a virtual function call.

#### Are there alternatives?

Because templates preserve type information, the compiler always knows which function to call. It's easy to inline templated function calls, and using them won't add overhead to your program.

If possible, prefer templates over virtual inheritance.